# Cannot disable data breakpoints in visual studio 2017 (Native c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, breakpoints

When I un-check a data breakpoint in the "Breakpoints" window an exception still occurs when the memory is written. If, however, I set the address in the settings to another value the exception does not occur. How can I fix this?

(Intel CORE I7, Windows 10, 32 bit native c++)

Is this a bug?
Are my expectations realistic that I should be able to disable a data breakpoint this way?

Comment: What is "data breakpoint"? How is it related to exception throwing? You should provide some example code.

Comment: @VTT Google 'What is "data breakpoints"'. I also know them as hardware breakpoints. The CPU traps a write to a memory range and throws a hardware exception. A kind of mini page fault.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience this is a bug (if the breakpoint is **unchecked**). And it is hard to replicate it. Just try to delete the Data Breakpoint. You should delete it anyhow since most likely it is **not valid for the next run** (the address of a variable changes from run to run).

Comment: Thanks, I think I may be able to just set the debugger to ignore the exception thrown. I had some strange exceptions at startup too that I just set to ignore. When the break point is disabled the annoying dialog telling you why it hit the break point is not displayed. Slight concern that ignoring the exception does not stop it happening, so effects timing of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot disable data breakpoints in visual studio 2017 (Native c++)

AFAIK, you do not need to disable the data breakpoints manually.

According to document [How to: Set a Data Breakpoint (Native Only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/350dyxd0(v=vs.100)):

> **Addresses of variables change from one debugging session to the next.
>   For this reason, data breakpoints are automatically disabled at the
>   end of each debugging session**.
>
> If you set a data breakpoint on a local variable, the data breakpoint
>   remains enabled when the function ends. However, the memory address it
>   is set on no longer has the same meaning. Therefore, the results of
>   such a breakpoint are unpredictable. **If you set a data breakpoint on a
>   local variable, the best practice is to remove or disable the
>   breakpoint before the function ends**.
>
> Visual Studio supports a maximum of four data breakpoints per
>   solution.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I manually disable it and it is still hit.